# React form and submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit, setstate

I'm trying to make a simple app where I communicate with the RIOT API. For this I have set up a SearchBar component, with a form and a submit button. All I'm trying to achieve is to get the name from the form after submission, save it to this.state.name and pass it down to the component that does the fetching. I just cant get a hold of event handlers...

```
  class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    
    handleChange(e){
        e.preventDefault()
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
<Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Control type="input" placeholder="Enter your summoner name" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                Let's go!
        </Button>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
</Form>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try update the form to use an `onSubmit` handler on the `Form` instead of on the button. Given the button has a type of `submit`, clicking on the button will trigger the form submit event, without the handler on the button. Also move the `preventDefault()` to the `onSubmit` rather than `onChange` to avoid the page from refreshing on submit event:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });

  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // send data to API
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Control type="input" placeholder="Enter your summoner name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Let's go!
        </Button>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!